# How load a local resource video file in html/php?

Tags: php, html

I had a dedicated server, my disk space went low, i purchased new one, i've placed my videos in D:\Videos\Abc.mp4. Now I can't be able to load then due to browser security restrictions.

In Chrome it says,

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

I had same issue for my photos in D:\Photos\Xyz.jpg and i used `file_get_contents()` in php and make a header to do the task,

Is there any alternative solution like i did with photos, with video files? Just any solution Or guidance please, i am stuck in this for days now.. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not because of browsers restriction, but incorrect url formation.

Your content are served from server, and you can not access any data from local machine(client). In your case you are giving a url which is local. Think it this way, if I open your url on my machine, I will not be able to view video as the same is missing on my machine.

Your file_get_contents() code worked as you are reading content from machine local to your server and then dumping it to client, same way you can do for video as well.

Comment: aah, i see, Thanks! I was not sure at first, now that you mentioned i looked more closely into php headers. I did found my way around it :)